# How do i create Palette UI object

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to create a type [`bpy.types.UILayout.template_palette`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=template_palette#bpy.types.UILayout.template_palette) in my `bpy.type.Panel`.

In my `bpy.type.Panel` I am unsure what object I need to pass to the first argument called `data`.

I think it needs an object with a property of type `bpy.types.Palette`. I am unsure what is a valid object that can be passed as `AnyType` and have a `bpy.types.Palette` property.

I have figured out how to make a `bpy.types.Palette` using 
`bpy.ops.palette.new()`.

I cant find a `bpy.props` function for adding a `bpy.types.Palette` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the [UILayout.template_palette](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=template_palette#bpy.types.UILayout.template_palette) you need data that has a property of type [bpy.types.Palette](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.Palette.html#bpy.types.Palette)

Here is a small test to add a new custom palette, assign it a couple of colors, yellow and red, set red as active.

The [image paint tool settings palette property](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.Paint.html?highlight=palette#bpy.types.Paint.palette) is assigned the new palette.

The palette is displayed in the image editor toolbar under the "misc" tab.

[image]

```
import bpy

class PaletteDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the tool panel of image editor"""
    bl_label = "Palette Demo"
    bl_idname = "IMAGE_PT_palette"
    bl_space_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        ts = context.tool_settings
        if ts.image_paint.palette:
            layout.template_palette(ts.image_paint, "palette", color=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PaletteDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PaletteDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # put some test code here to create palette etc
    # add a new pallete
    pal = bpy.data.palettes.get("CustomPalette")
    if pal is None:
        pal = bpy.data.palettes.new("CustomPalette")
        # add a color to that palette
        yellow = pal.colors.new()
        yellow.color = (1, 1, 0)
        yellow.weight = 1.0

        red = pal.colors.new()
        red.color = (1, 0, 0)

        # make red active
        pal.colors.active = red

    ts = bpy.context.tool_settings   
    ts.image_paint.palette = pal
```