# How to get a specific color/slot from a Color Palette

Tags: python, color, palettes

i'm currently trying out a few different things and hit a wall when I was trying to get the rgb value of a color in a palette:
[image]

I'm looking for the RGB Value of one of the colors in this palette, and i want to get it by python and not just by "what slot is active" but by some sort of ID/Name, my next idea was to go to the Blender File API and look there for the Datapath of the individual color to get an idea how i would need to write my script, however right clicking on it there, does not reveal the usual feature to "copy Data Path" so i suspect that the information is stored somewhere deeper and that i need to access it in another way.

[image]
*Sidenote: It would be really great if we were able to Change the name of the individual colors here and i think that is something that is planned.*

My final goal would be to get the color and with that set the color of a material on an object, the last part of it i already got down.

Has anyone an idea how i could get the vaulue? I was only able to get the data path up to the Palette itself:

```
bpy.data.palettes["PaletteTest"].name
```

But not on the values it contains.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73137/15543

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Palette has a colors collection.**

Example of displaying and  creating palettes.  [How do i create Palette UI object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73122/how-do-i-create-palette-ui-object)

Add a new palette,

```
>>> pal = D.palettes.new("Test")
```

The palettes color collection holds objects of type `bpy.types.PaletteColor`.  The color is its `PaletteColor.color` property

give it 10 random colors.

```
>>> from random import random
>>> for i in range(10):
...     col = pal.colors.new()
...     col.color = (random(), random(), random())
...
```

All the palettes in the file (just the new one for example)

```
>>> for pal in D.palettes:
...     pal.name
...     
'Test'
```

Get that particular palette, *will be `None` if it doesn't exist*

```
>>> pal = bpy.data.palettes.get("Test")
```

display its colors..

```
>>> for col in pal.colors:
...     col.color[:]
...     
(0.9453005194664001, 0.5010330677032471, 0.5785542726516724)
(0.8932003378868103, 0.4246959388256073, 0.30071189999580383)
(0.867354154586792, 0.40056300163269043, 0.9528054594993591)
(0.9828635454177856, 0.22360216081142426, 0.7132857441902161)
(0.6740276217460632, 0.6160644888877869, 0.43397003412246704)
(0.65944504737854, 0.4424607753753662, 0.7807620763778687)
(0.8238367438316345, 0.5752789378166199, 0.6956546306610107)
(0.11555215716362, 0.7942420244216919, 0.33690154552459717)
(0.026920389384031296, 0.7090178728103638, 0.9057185053825378)
(0.36781519651412964, 0.18919502198696136, 0.32881513237953186)

>>>
```

Comment: So bpy.data.palettes.get("PaletteName".colors returns a list/array with all entries in it, how would i get a specific one from that, like the fifth as an example?

Comment: AFAIK the colors aren't assigned name. Index by number `pal.colors[0]` is the first, etc. & `foo.get("bar").prop` defeats the purpose, throwing an error  if `foo.bar is None`.   Instead `if not pal:`.

Comment: Ah okay, i think with the value that is returned its not possible to just straight put it into the value of an RGB Node ... .nodes["NameOfNode"].outputs[0].default_value = (bpy.data.palettes.get("PaletteTest").colors[5]). I get an error doing that : ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequence expected at dimension 1, not 'PaletteColor'

Comment: `r, g, b = pal.colors[4].color` is the (r, g, b) value given to the 5th color. (_ie_ Use the color attribute as shown in answer)  Some nodes may require an alpha, `default_value = (r, g, b, 1)`

Comment: that did it! Thank you very much :) !