# Display preset RGB values in a panel (and call function when clicked)

Tags: python, interface, panel

For clarity, this question was closed for a while after I added the clarifying statement inside the parenthesis so I created a [new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252020/how-to-display-a-fixed-list-of-rgb-values-in-a-panel-and-when-a-color-is-clicked) asking the same thing. This question was later opened and now there are two very similar questions.

I have a panel in which I want to display a few preset colours that a user could then click on but not change the value of (IE, I **don't** want the colour-picker dialogue to pop up like when clicking a `FloatVectorProperty`). When a color is clicked I want to call a function to do some things behind the scenes.

This image from windows paint is basically what I want:

[image: Paint image showing colour boxes]

You can use `layout.template_node_socket(color=(R, G, B, A))` but as far as I know there's no way to make it clickable, neither do I think its very good UI wise (I'd much rather have a square).

So my question, is there a way to display a coloured square that's clickable (and calls a function) in the UI?

**EDIT**

[In this gif from @pyCod3R (using a palette)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251861/) its showing the colors exactly how I'd like it to be but there is a <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> sign which adds/removes indices to the list. I **can't** allow users to modify the list because its fixed and no items should be added or removed.

From what I can tell there isn't a way to call a function when a color inside the palette is clicked, am I wrong and there is a way to do it?

Comment: You want to use a color palette. see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228575/how-to-get-a-specific-color-slot-from-a-color-palette) for how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i create Palette UI object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73122/how-do-i-create-palette-ui-object)

Comment: My question was poorly formulated, a palette is only a partial solution unless I'm missing how to remove the "+"/"-" signs and how to call a function when a color is clicked.

Answer (score 6):

#### Have a look into [How do i create Palette UI object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73122/how-do-i-create-palette-ui-object) and [How to get a specific color/slot from a Color Palette](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228575/how-to-get-a-specific-color-slot-from-a-color-palette)

Quickly combined the code of both answers to display 50 random generated colors and their rgb values directly on the panel. Notice that `Alpha` is not supported, `PaletteColor` is a float array of 3 items: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PaletteColor.html#bpy.types.PaletteColor

[image]

Minor changes to @batFINGERs code from: [How do i create Palette UI object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73137/)

```
import bpy

class PaletteDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the tool panel of image editor"""
    bl_label = "Palette Demo"
    bl_idname = "MATERIAL_PT_palette"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        ts = context.tool_settings
        palette = ts.image_paint.palette
        sel_r, sel_g, sel_b = palette.colors.active.color
        
        if ts.image_paint.palette:
            layout.template_palette(ts.image_paint, "palette", color=True)
            layout.label(text="Active Color: {:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}".format(
                sel_r, 
                sel_g, 
                sel_b))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PaletteDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PaletteDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # Add a new pallete
    pal = bpy.data.palettes.get("CustomPalette")
    if pal is None:
        pal = bpy.data.palettes.new("CustomPalette")

        # Add a single color
        red = pal.colors.new()
        red.color = (1, 0, 0)

        # Add random colors to the palette
        from random import random
        for i in range(50):
            col = pal.colors.new()
            col.color = (random(), random(), random())

        # Make red the active/selected color
        pal.colors.active = red

    ts = bpy.context.tool_settings   
    ts.image_paint.palette = pal
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: How would I trigger a function call when a color is picked?

Comment: Is there a way to disable the "+" and "-" signs? I **cant** allow the users to add more or remove colors since the list is fixed.

Comment: @CybranM `template_palette()` is hard coded in C. I'll do some research and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to achieve a **very similar result** and **trigger an event** is to use a series of `BoolProperties` (as elements of a collection) which also allows to have an **active item**.

The principle is the same as in my [prevoius answer using operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252436/139380). You can display the `BoolProperty` only as an icon and generate the **icons for the colors on the fly** by adding a new [preview collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.previews.html#bpy.utils.previews.ImagePreviewCollection) (as you normally would do for custom icons) and then assigning a pixel array of the color to each new *icon* added: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImagePreview.html

[image]

Example of a color palette using `BoolProperties` and assigning the selected color to the object's diffuse color property using the update function (make sure viewport shading is set to solid).

```
import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews
from random import uniform


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        active_item = None
        for idx, item in enumerate(scn.color_collection, start=1):
            row.prop(item, "active", icon_value=item.icon, icon_only=True)
            if item.active == True:
                active_item = item
            if idx % 11 == 0:
                row = col.row(align=True)
            
        if active_item:
            row = layout.row()
            r, g, b, a = active_item.color
            row.label(text=f"Active item: {r:.2f} {g:.2f} {b:.2f} {a:.2f}")                


def random_rbga(alpha=1):
    return (uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), alpha)

def update_callback(self, context):
    if self.active:
        for i in self.id_data.color_collection:
            if i.name != self.name:
                i.active = False
    # set the diffuse color
    obj = context.object
    obj.active_material.diffuse_color = self.color

class ColorCollection(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # name: bpy.props.StringProperty
    active: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False, update=update_callback)
    icon: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    color: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
         name = "Color",
         subtype = "COLOR",
         default = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),
         size = 4)


# We can store multiple preview collections here,
# however in this example we only store "main"
preview_collections = {}

def register():
    
    # register the classes
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColorCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.color_collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=ColorCollection)
    
    # clear the collection
    if hasattr(bpy.context.scene, "color_collection"):
        bpy.context.scene.color_collection.clear()
        
    # generate colors and icons
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    
    size = 32, 32
    for i in range(32):
        
        color_name = f"Color{i}"
        color = random_rbga(alpha=1)
        pixels = [*color] * size[0] * size[1]
        icon = pcoll.new(color_name) # name has to be unique!
        icon.icon_size = size
        icon.is_icon_custom = True
        icon.icon_pixels_float = pixels
        
        # add the item to the collection
        color_item = bpy.context.scene.color_collection.add()
        color_item.name = color_name
        color_item.color = color
        color_item.icon = pcoll[color_name].icon_id
        
    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    

def unregister():
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()
    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColorCollection)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.color_collection


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want somewhat similar without all the extra elements coming with `template_palette()` IE <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, a fixed list and also execute an operator when the user clicks one of the colors... you can implement some sort of dynamic operator for all colors, and display only the icon on the panel.

[image]

Example script using some of the default icons (If you want to use custom icons, have a look into: [How to implement custom icons for my script/addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32335/how-to-implement-custom-icons-for-my-script-addon)).

```
import bpy

colors = {
    0: {"Color": (0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0),
        "Icon": 'COLORSET_01_VEC'},
    1: {"Color": (0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0),
        "Icon": 'COLORSET_02_VEC'},
    2: {"Color": (1.0, 0.4, 0.5, 1.0),
        "Icon": 'COLORSET_08_VEC'},
}

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    
    color: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
             name = "Color Picker",
             subtype = "COLOR",
             size = 4)

    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.active_color = self.color
        print(self.color[0], self.color[1], self.color[2], self.color[3])
        return {'FINISHED'}


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.column_flow(columns=18)
        for k, v in colors.items(): 
            p = row.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="", icon=v.get("Icon"))
            p.color = v.get("Color")
        
        r, g, b, a = context.scene.active_color
        layout.row().label(text=f"Active Color: {r:.2f}, {g:.2f}, {b:.2f}, {a:.2f}")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.active_color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
             name = "Color Picker",
             subtype = "COLOR",
             default = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),
             size = 4)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    del bpy.Scene.active_color

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

UI code comes from [Could I see a simple example of using a color picker in a script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214347)

To refute claims in the comments, it works with custom icons (32x32 px) representing the colors as expected:

[image]